# How does SonarQube knows which sensors to run for build?

Tags: sonarqube, teamcity, sonarqube-scan

I have following situation - in Teamcity I set up two builds for sonar

1. First - by use of `maven sonar:sonar`
2. Second - with special teamcity step "SonarQube"

In the second case I see in sonar logs that it run Jacoco sensors, but in the first case, when running from maven, Jacoco sensors did not start.

So, I have a general question about this situation - who controls which sensors will be started for a build? Is it some environment variables that I should setup for maven, or is it somehow controled by SonarQube server?

Comment: Which plugins have you installed?

Comment: jacoco plugin installed on both sides TC and Sonar, as I mentioned in question with SonarQube step "I see in sonar logs that it run Jacoco sensors"

Answer (score 3):

Sensor itself describes when it should be executed - see https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/4.5.0.8398/java-jacoco/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/jacoco/JaCoCoSensor.java#L65 and https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/6.2.1/sonar-plugin-api/src/main/java/org/sonar/api/batch/sensor/SensorDescriptor.java#L37-L42